# Thermal averages with opposite sign in the exponential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, tight-binding

I've recently seen an example where a thermal average was carried using a plus sign instead of the usual minus sign inside the exponential.

$$\langle \mu \rangle = \frac{1}{Z} tr(e^{\beta H }\mu) \qquad\qquad Z = 
 tr(e^{\beta H }) $$

I have simplified the equations they have used to keep it clear, the form of $\mu$ is not important but it is used to calculate the hole mobilities $\langle \mu \rangle $ of a crystal. $H$ is essentially a tight binding type Hamiltonian

$$H = \sum_{n}E_{n}\vert n \rangle\langle n \vert + \sum_{n,n'}V_{nn'}\vert n \rangle \langle n' \vert$$

where $\vert n \rangle$ are charge localised (hole) states, this is also written in second quantisation in some papers. I've heard some say that the sign change in the exponential is necessary so that you sum over the top of the band structure or something. However this sounds like a mistake because this idea of filling the top of band structure refers to hole occupations of the orbitals of the many-body wavefunction $\vert n \rangle$ right? So since we are taking the trace over eigenstates  $\vert \psi_{n} \rangle$ of $H$ which are a linear-combination of $\vert n \rangle$ shouldn't we be using the usual $e^{-\beta H }$ factor?

Source: https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpcc.8b11916 Eq.~8 + Eq.~10

Comment: Is it possible to know the $H(\mu)$ dependence?

Comment: So the full equations is $L^{2}_{x} = \frac{1}{Z}\sum_{n,m} e^{\beta H}\langle \psi_{n} \vert  j_{x} \vert \psi_{m} \rangle \langle \psi_{m} \vert  j_{x} \vert \psi_{n} \rangle \frac{2}{(\hbar / \tau) - (E_{m} - E_{n})^{2}}$ and $\langle \mu \rangle = \frac{e}{kT}\frac{L^{2}_{x}}{2\tau}$ where $\psi_{m}$  are the eigenvectors of $H$ and $ j_{x} $ are current operators.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpcc.8b11916 source for the above equation

Comment: Also the system is put under periodic boundary conditions so the summations are large but finite.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of states or the energy is not bounded, then $e^{\beta H}$ is not a well-defined probability distribution (cannot be normalized). Sometimes, the minus sign is just included in the definition of the Hamiltonian or in the $\beta$ parameter.

EDIT: Now that I remember this is the usual trick when dealing with holes. In the typical simplest model for particle absorption, in which particles have an energy $\epsilon_1=\epsilon$ if they are stuck to a lattice with $N$ nodes or energy $\epsilon_1=0$ otherwise. Then the number of absorbed particles is:

$N_{particles}=\frac{N}{1+e^{-\frac{\epsilon}{kt}}}$

You can compute from here the statistics for the holes using $N=N_{
particles}+N_{holes}$

$N_{holes}=\frac{N}{1+e^{\frac{\epsilon}{kt}}}$

So you could think of the holes as particles that have an energy spectrum that is the negative version of the original particles.

Comment: ok so in this paper https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpcc.9b01902 they state that "Note that for hole carriers, the thermal weighting factor must be adapted by changing the sign in the exponent".

Comment: Yes, reading the paper I remembered that you can do this kind of thing with the holes. Basically, if you were to compute the partition function for the particles, you would be using the proper $e^{-\beta H}$ weight. I edited my answer to give an example.

Comment: Are you sure that is right? The $N_{particles}$ and $N_{holes}$ comes from the fermi-dirac statistics of electron and holes and is for the case of a noninteracting wavefunction of fermions right? However the wavefunctions $\vert \psi_{n} \rangle$ are the eigenstates of $H$ and would be formed from a basis set of noninteracting wavefunctions $\vert n \rangle$ . So you wouldn't use fermi-dirac statistics here because we run the thermal average over states $\vert \psi_{n} \rangle$ rather then electron/hole occupations. I'm using a slightly different notation to the paper.

Comment: Honestly, I am not 100% sure. This is rather an intuition. However, I think that this result for the $N_{particles}$ and the $N_{holes}$ would stand if you use the thermal average over the states $|\psi_n>$, this is, the canonical ensemble ($<N_\epsilon>=\frac{Ne^{-\beta \epsilon}}{Z}$)

Comment: Is that right? Isn't $\langle N_{\epsilon} \rangle = \frac{Ne^{-\beta \epsilon}}{Z}$ for a noninteracting case? $H$ in my example includes off diagonal terms so $\langle N_{\epsilon} \rangle = \frac{1}{Z} tr (e^{-\beta H} N_{\epsilon})$ which is not equal to the previous equation as far as I can tell.

Comment: I don't think that $<N_\epsilon>=\frac{Ne^{-\beta \epsilon}}{Z}$ in your case. What I am trying to say is that it is possible to understand this change in the sign of the weights ($e^{\beta \epsilon_i}$) in a simpler case with non-interacting particles. From this simpler result, you get some intuition about why it might be possible to use these "positive" weights for the statistics of the holes instead of the usual Boltzmann weights. But this is more a fishy inference rather than a rigorous explanation.